# Spark Structured Streaming for appending to text file using foreach

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I want to append lines to a text file using structured streaming. This code results in `SparkException: Task not serializable`. I think `toDF` is not allowed. How could I get this code to work?

```
df.writeStream
  .foreach(new ForeachWriter[Row] {
    override def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long): Boolean = {
      true 
    }

    override def process(row: Row): Unit = {
       val df = Seq(row.getString(0)).toDF

       df.write.format("text").mode("append").save(output)
    } 

    override def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {
    }      
  }).start
```

Comment: i think you should try this 
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).textFile("Path_To_Store")

Comment: Compiler complains that textFile is not a member of DataFramerWriter. I'm using spark 2.1.

Comment: sorry its only `text("Path_To_Save")` 
`df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).text("Path_To_Save")`

Comment: Is the issue resolved. I'm trying to do a poc https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64863847/spark-streaming-consuming-message-from-socket-and-processing-null-pointer-exc

Comment: @zsxwing Can you please help to reslove the issue
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64863847/spark-streaming-consuming-message-from-socket-and-processing-null-pointer-exc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call `df.write.format("text").mode("append").save(output)` inside `process` method. It will run in the executor side. You can use the file sink instead, such as

```
df.writeStream.format("text")....
```

Comment: This does work, although I was planning to vary the output path in the foreach code, depending on what's in row. I'll need to find a way to do that.

Comment: Not sure if you can just use `DataStreamWriter.partitionBy`

Comment: Beautiful, yes. Thank you very much.